# Which typical server/headless Ubuntu packages have a dependency to Snapd?

Tags: server, package-management, 22.04, cloud

I was quite surprised to find the `Snapd` package present in a server/headless Ubuntu image aimed at cloud environments `jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img` but zero packages installed actually depending on it.

Can you list server-like/headless software packaged for `Snapd` in Ubuntu 22.04 which may motivate such a move?

Edit: Changed the question to enable answers ;)

Comment: "why" is impossible to answer.  "Will all normal application packages in Ubuntu end up as Snap packages in future versions?" we can't answer that.

Comment: Unfortunately, the LetsEncrypt `certbot` instructions ask one to install it via snap. This is the only snap application I've considered installing in my server.

Comment: LXD, which I use extensively for containers and VMs on my servers, is distributed as a Snap.

Comment: I now accept certbot and LXD as answers.